# null value in column "assigned_facilities_id"

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access the dictonary inside the jsonfield serializer "assigned_facilities". But i'm receiving the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "assigned_facilities_id" of relation "users_leadfacilityassign" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (78, null, null, 159).

File "/app/users/api/views.py", line 53, in perform_create
serializer.save(agent=self.request.user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/app/users/api/serializers.py", line 252, in create
instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities.get('facility_id'), datetime=assigned_facilities.get('datetime'))
```

I'm basically trying to create a "LeadFacilityAssign" object for each item inside my json so i can have a "LeadFacilityAssign" object for each facility i want to add to a lead.

Does anyone know what is causing this error? I tried a few different things but nothing worked so far.

json

```
{
    "facilities": [{
            "facility_id": "1",
            "datetime": "2018-12-19 09:26:03.478039"
        },
        {
            "facility_id": "1",
            "datetime": "2018-12-19 09:26:03.478039"
        }
    ]
}
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    assigned_facilities = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "is_owner",
            "assigned_facilities",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "is_owner")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
    
  def create(self, validated_data):
        
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for facility in assigned_facilities:
            instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities.get('facility_id'), datetime=assigned_facilities.get("datetime"))
            
        return instance
```

models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

class LeadFacilityAssign(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facility, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leadfacility')
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leadfacility')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
class LeadCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLeadOwner]
    serializer_class = LeadUpdateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(agent=self.request.user)

class LeadUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLeadOwner]
    serializer_class = LeadUpdateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lead.objects.all()
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not have to access to id and datetime like a dict ? assigned_facilities["facility_id"] and assigned_facilities["datetime"]

Comment: You mean like this?             ```instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities["facility_id"],datetime=assigned_facilities["datetime"])```
That will return: 
KeyError: 'facility_id'

Answer (score 3):

You have three tables:

1. Lead table in which lead_id is non nullable since it is primary key
2. Facility table in which facility_id is non nullable since it is primary key
3. LeadFacility table in which lead_facility_id is non nullable but its two foreign keys (lead_id and facility_id) are nullable.
   And you are assigning these nullable value to your non nullable field.

Maybe you are trying to do :
**lead_falility_id (table: LeadFacility talbe) = facility_id (table: Facility)**

But by mistake you are doing :
**lead_falility_id (table: LeadFacility talbe) = facility_id (table: LeadFacility).**

And because of this, your are doing :
lead_facility_id = null for the non nullable field.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON doesn't match your serializer.
Your serializer fields don't match your model fields.
Your views don't match your models or your serializers.

So, let's take it from the top.

If I understand correctly, you want to create a LeadFacilityAssign object at the same time as creating or updating a Lead object. There are some approaches to solve this, like using a post_save signal right after a Lead create request, but let's follow your drift...

From your Lead serializer, this is "fine":

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    assigned_facilities = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "is_owner",
            "assigned_facilities",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "is_owner")
```

But this:

```
    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
```

Has a comparison statement (==) in the last line, meaning it could return a True or False value (?), plus you're not using the "agent" field anywhere else, nor is declared in the serializer or even a field in your models. Just get rid of that function or add the "agent" field in your LeadFacilityAssign model (assuming you'll assign a Lead, a Facility and an Agent to that relationship).

What I'm guessing you're expecting from you JSON call is the "facilities" info. From your declared fields above I guess you should be expecting an "assigned_facilities" field, which doesn't show in your JSON data, but let's assume your API will receive an "assigned_facilities" field instead of the "facilities" sub-dict with many facilities related to a single Lead.

I haven't tested the code below, but according to the REST API docs, you have to define two methods in your serializer now, one for CREATE and one for UPDATE.

Create:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    lead = Lead.objects.create(first_name=validated_data['first_name'], last_name=validated_data['last_name'] #Here you will create the Lead object that you will reference later in your LeadFacilityAssign relationship with the dictionary information from the received data, so let's save it:
    lead.save()
    #Now we need to create all facilities relationships to this Lead:
    facilities = validated_data['assigned_facilities'] #This will create a "facilities" sub-dict from your received data with a facility_id and a datetime field in key-value pair.
    for item in facilities:
        facility = Facility.objects.get(id=item['facility_id']) #Get a single facility object for each ID in your JSON. If this fails, try converting it to int().
        datetime = item['datetime']  #Again, if it fails because it's taken as string, try converting it to datetime object.
        entry = LeadFacilityAssign.objects.create(assigned_facilities=facility, lead=lead, datetime=datetime) #Create the entry.
        entry.save() #Save the entry
    return #Exit your function
```

The Update method should look more or less the same.

In the view, if you're not using the "agent" field just parse the user it for safety or just use it later if you want to include it as owner in your model.

```
class LeadCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLeadOwner]
    serializer_class = LeadUpdateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON sample include "facilities" but your serializer has `assigned_facilities = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True, write_only=True)`.

```py
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    facilities = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "PrimaryAddress",
            "City",
            "PostalCode",
            "RegionOrState",
            "pc_email",
            "Cell",
            "secphone",
            "client_cell",
            "client_secphone",
            "birthday",
            "curr_client_address",
            "curr_client_city",
            "curr_client_zip",
            "ideal_address",
            "ideal_city",
            "ideal_zip",
            "ideal_state",
            "budget",
            "client_email",
            "client_first_name",
            "client_last_name",
            "lead_status",
            "created_at",
            "agent",
            "is_owner",
            "relationship",
            "marital_status",
            "gender",
            "pets",
            "facilities",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "created_at", "agent", "is_owner")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        
        facilities = validated_data.pop("facilities", None)
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for facilities in assigned_facilities:
             LeadFacilityAssign.objects.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities.get("facility_id"), datetime=assigned_facilities.get("datetime"), lead=instance)

        return instance
```

Also you added required False for facilities, so validated.pop("facilities") might be caused error if there is no facilities in request. You should add another parameter into pop method. validated.pop("facilities", None)

Comment: I changed the json aswell as the serializer by your recommendation but it returns a null constraint error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "assigned_facilities_id" of relation "users_leadfacilityassign" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (70, null, null, 149).

Comment: I updated my post below with the updated code

Comment: You can not create instance via related_name. I updated my answer

Comment: It still returns: ```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "assigned_facilities_id" of relation "users_leadfacilityassign" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (73, null, null, 152).
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your Query will become like this

```
instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id__id=assigned_facilities.get('facility_id'), datetime=assigned_facilities.get("datetime"))
```

#### NOTE-

because `assigned_facilities_id` return full object of foreign key & `assigned_facilities_id__id` return value of id foreign key object